# Adding shard in collection using collection API in solr

Tags: collections, solr, sharding

I am using **Apache solr** to create **collection**, **shards**. I am able to build **collection** using

```
sudo curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=demo&numShards=2&replicationFactor=1'
```

Here, **collection name = "demo"
number of Shards = "2"**

but when I am adding new shard using

```
sudo curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATESHARD&shard=shard3&collection=demo'
```

It is giving **error** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">1</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">shards can be added only to 'implicit' collections</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation for CREATESHARD](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API):

> Shards can only created with this API for collections that use the 'implicit' router. Use SPLITSHARD for collections using the 'compositeId' router. A new shard with a name can be created for an existing 'implicit' collection.

So the proper way to do this is to issue a SPLITSHARD command instead, and then remove the old shard after the two new shards have been created. From the SPLITSHARD documentation:

> Splitting a shard will take an existing shard and break it into two pieces. The original shard will continue to contain the same data as-is but it will start re-routing requests to the new shards. The new shards will have as many replicas as the original shard. After splitting a shard, you should issue a commit to make the documents visible, and then you can remove the original shard (with the Core API or Solr Admin UI) when ready.

Comment: `@MatsLindh :` Sounds nice! It splits the `original shard` into `2 sub-shards` which contains parts of original shard. What I want is that to create `new(fresh) shard`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Not unless you use the implicit router (meaning that you send the documents to a specific shard manually yourself). The implicit router is chosen if you don't set a numShards option - setting the option uses the compositeId router.

Answer (score 0):

Shards can only created with this API for collections that use the 'implicit' router (i.e., when the collection was created, router.name=implicit). A new shard with a name can be created for an existing 'implicit' collection.

reference,https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/collection-management.html